# Selenium WebDriver ignoring the conditional logic written in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, if-statement, webdriver

This is a simple sign-in script which I am running in Firefox.
What I am trying to do is to print a message if the sign-in is successful or fails.
I gave wrong user/pass to get the error (verified it against the site that it's correct).

The **page-title** element only displays if user was logged-in successfully. Similarly, the **error-msg** element only displays if user was not logged-in.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://www.example.com";
    String actualTitle;

    // Launch Firefox and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Maximize the browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Get the actual value of the title
    actualTitle = driver.getTitle();


    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Signin")).click();

    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
    email.click();
    email.sendKeys("abc@example.com");

    WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
    pass.click();
    pass.sendKeys("abc123456");

    driver.findElement(By.id("send2")).click();



    // Variables for Dashboard & Error Title
    WebElement dashboardTitle = driver.findElement(By.className("page-title"));
    WebElement loginFailed = driver.findElement(By.className("error-msg"));

    if(loginFailed.getText().contains("Invalid login or password."))
        System.out.println("Test passed but login failed.");
    else if(dashboardTitle.getText().contains("My Dashboard"))
        System.out.println("Logged in successfully.");
    else if(dashboardTitle.getText().contains("Account Information"))
            System.out.println("Logged in successfully.");
    else
        System.out.println("You're not logged-in.");

    System.out.println("The title of current page is: "+actualTitle);
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
```

User/Pass are not correct so the 'IF' condition should run but in reality it's giving me error that other element (page-title) is not found.

If I remove the other condition (from IF statement) then the script is running without any issue.

I want the script to run and search for both elements and if it finds only one element (which it should be) then it should display it's result instead of giving me the error that other element is not found.

Comment: What is the output from `loginFailed.getText()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code solved my issue:

```
Boolean exist;
    if(exist = driver.findElements(By.className("page-title")).size() == 0){
        WebElement errorMessage = driver.findElement(By.className("error-msg"));

        if(errorMessage.getText().contains("Invalid login or passwords.")){
            System.out.println("Test passed but login failed.");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("error-msg class found but different message in it.");
    }

    else{
        WebElement dashboardTitle = driver.findElement(By.className("page-title"));
        if(dashboardTitle.getText().contains("Account Information"))
            System.out.println("Logged in successfully.");
        else
            System.out.println("LOGGED IN");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-catch block.

```
....
....
driver.findElement(By.id("send2")).click();

try {
    WebElement dashboardTitle = driver.findElement(By.className("page-title"));
    System.out.println("Logged in successfully.");
    /* Continue code for correct login credentials
     *
     */
} catch(NoSuchElementException e) {

}

try {
    WebElement loginFailed = driver.findElement(By.className("error-msg"));
    System.out.println("Test passed but login failed.");
    /* Continue code for incorrect login credentials
     *
     */
} catch(NoSuchElementException e) {

}

System.out.println("The title of current page is: "+actualTitle);
driver.close();
driver.quit();
....
....
```

Comment: Same error "Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"page-title"}"

Comment: @Alam - Check the edit. Remove the `if` statement after the try-catch block

Comment: Removing the IF statement will give the Syntax error because the variables are used in IF statement to check whether they have the required text or not.

Comment: @Alam - The first statements in the `try` will help you detect if the login credentials are valid or the login credentials are invalid. You won't need the `if` statement for that.

Comment: @Alam - If the login credentials are valid then add the code for **valid user** in the **first** try block after the `syso` statement. If the login credentials are invalid then add the code for **invalid user** in the **second** try block after the `syso` statement.

Comment: It's still not working. How to add code in the comment? The backticks are not working for me.

Comment: @Alam - Do you know how to use comments in Java?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about adding code here (in SO's comments).

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Try using pastebin.com or gist.github.com to add code and paste the link here..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to find a web element, this should help you wait and find element, if element not found it will catch the exception and return null or else a WebElement.

```
public WebElement waitAndGetElement(WebDriver driver, By by, int waitTimeInSeconds) {
   try {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTimeInSeconds).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by)); 
   } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
}
```

Example:

```
WebElement loginFailed = waitAndGetElement(driver, By.className("error-msg"), 5);

if(loginFailed != null && loginFailed.getText().contains("Invalid login or password."))
    System.out.println("Test passed but login failed.");
```